# Good Product Management Software

Tags: sql-server, interface, content-management-system

Currently, we have information about our products in a variety of places.

ERP, Various Databases, etc. Generally we're using SQL Server to store most of the database.

We want to create a centralized place where we can store all the information related to our products and start replacing these disjoint databases (with the exception of the ERP).

What are some good software packages that will handle thousands of products, have a HTML interface and perhaps a Win32 client as well. Be able to handle Web Friendly Data, internal only data and be customizable. (If I want to add a product features section, I do that... if I want to set the attributes to be in a specific order when displayed I'd like to be able to order them).

Our ERP has some information, but it's not normalized data, it's not standardized and won't hold everything about the product.

Are there any good software packages that will maintain a database of products that we can hook into ( for product information, reporting, showing on the web etc. ) or do I have to roll my own?

The problem isn't in rolling the database, it's all about the interface and the ability to add attributes to products, add different things in different languages etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pimcore.org/

- PHP & MySQL based
- handle thousands of products without any problems
- incl. DAM
- Versioning, Scheduling, Permissions, ....
- Easy interfaces to connect ERP, ...
- Web-Client but no Win32

The WCMS component can be turned off.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. I'd prefer it if it were based on the Microsoft Stack (Asp.Net), though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to manage product in an organization is using [ERP software](http://www.essindia.com/) because its save the lot of time and you can easily handle your database in a single location.

Comment: A more detailed answer is sought by the OP. Please elaborate your answer. Also, the link to  http://www.essindia.com/ is unwarranted.